# PHP error in wordpress site HTTP ERROR 500 after editing template

Tags: php, wordpress

After editing a template in a `PHP` file in my theme, I pressed save changes, after I got a HTTP 500 ERROR, now i am trying to paste back the code to the exact same place, it is still returning a error. What is solution to fix the code?

**CODE**

```
function the_archive_title( $before = '', $after = '' ) {

   if ( is_category() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Category: %s', 'tesseract' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );

 } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Tag: %s', 'tesseract' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) );

} elseif ( is_author() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Author: %s', 'tesseract' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );

}

} elseif ( is_tag() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Tag: %s', 'tesseract' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) );

} elseif ( is_author() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Author: %s', 'tesseract' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );

} elseif ( is_year() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Year: %s', 'tesseract' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'tesseract' ) ) );

} elseif ( is_month() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Month: %s', 'tesseract' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'tesseract' ) ) );

} elseif ( is_day() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Day: %s', 'tesseract' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F j, Y', 'daily archives date format', 'tesseract' ) ) );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-aside' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Asides', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-gallery' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Galleries', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-image' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Images', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-video' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Videos', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-quote' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Quotes', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-link' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Links', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-status' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Statuses', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-audio' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Audio', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-chat' ) ) {

    $title = _x( 'Chats', 'post format archive title', 'tesseract' );

} elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'tesseract' ), post_type_archive_title( '', false ) );

} elseif ( is_tax() ) {

    $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );

    /* translators: 1: Taxonomy singular name, 2: Current taxonomy term */

    $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s', 'tesseract' ), $tax->labels->singular_name, single_term_title( '', false ) );

} else {

    $title = __( 'Archives', 'tesseract' );

}
```

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error means that you probably has some parsing error or typo somewhere, you can check your error log (likely in /var/log/ directory depend on type of server you used) or turn on error checking by change the setting on wp_config.php.

Comment: Ok, is it possible I could have broken the whole site?

Comment: If what you posted is your entire function, then you have a missing close `}` at  the end.

Comment: at the end where sorry

Comment: Your function has open `{` but without `}`. At least this is what you posted.

Comment: sorry I have posted the whole function now

Comment: Is that the actual function? It got invalid amount of braces and a few if statements are repeating. If it is a copy/paste mistake, _please take your time and make sure you post the actual code_. Also, as other have pointed out, check your error log or turn on display errors to get the actual error message. No need to guess what the error is when you can let PHP tell you..

Comment: Please turn on the error reporting and paste the error which you are getting. You can turn on the error reporting by updating your **wp-config.php** Added these

  

    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

Set this to true if not in a production environment.

    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);


You can read more about debugging on WordPress at [Debugging in WordPress][1]


  [1]: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I am in the process of trying to access my files through FTP, But this server hosting does not seem to have any FTP already set up. Is there any other way to access my wp-config file. My hosting is my.vultr.com.

Comment: Ask their support. What does you accessing the files through FTP have to do with your issue? Did you solve it locally? How were you able to get your site on to the server in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to paste back the code?

If you have modified the *functions.php* file and did that in **Appearance > Editor** and didn't refresh the page, you might visually see that reverted code gets saved, but in reality the Appearance Editor does nothing since there is an error in *functions.php*.

Solution is to revert back the code in *functions.php* using other means, like FTP or using editor in cPanel / Plesk.